# ORACLE Trigger Check Table and delete row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, mutating-table

Hey I got a little Problem with creating a trigger at my Database.

I have an Table that's named 'located' and contains:

- Country
- City
- Province
- Lake
- Sea
- River

So Lake, Sea and River are Foreign Keys.

I created these three constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE located
ADD CONSTRAINT locatedLake
        FOREIGN KEY (lake)
        REFERENCES Lake(name)
        ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE located
ADD CONSTRAINT locatedRiver
        FOREIGN KEY (river)
        REFERENCES River(name)
        ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE located
ADD CONSTRAINT locatedSea
        FOREIGN KEY (sea)
        REFERENCES Sea(name)
        ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

So every time I delete a lake, river or sea in located it's set to NULL.

Now I tried to create this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deleteFromLocated
AFTER UPDATE ON located
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        DROP FROM located WHERE sea IS NULL AND river IS NULL AND lake IS NULL;
END;
/
```

But then I get a MUTATING ERROR.

The Goal is to delete every tuple where these three things are null.

Maybe someone can help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a trigger?  Assuming a production system where you care about performance, that would require three triggers and a package (or temp table) or an 11g compound trigger with multiple parts.  That's generally a bad solution.  Could you create a constraint that prevents all three columns from being NULL and then modify the application to delete the `located` row when it deletes from the parent table?

Comment: This is a task we have to solve for a lecture. Database is fixed and usage of a trigger is required. We will probably solve this task with 3 triggers. However, this solution is some kind of unsatisfying, if you know what i mean...

Answer (score 1):

First, `FOR EACH ROW` isn't helping you here since you're not using `:new` or `:old` do handle the specific row being updated. You could try removing `FOR EACH ROW`. (I don't have an environment to test with right now sorry)

Really this doesn't seem like a good use of triggers. You could instead:

- Always follow lake, river, and sea table deletions with`DELETE FROM located WHERE sea IS NULL AND river IS NULL AND lake IS NULL;`
- Create procedures delete_lake, etc. which delete from the lake table then delete from located.
- More efficiently, really, you should do either of these two approaches but delete the rows first (`DELETE FROM located WHERE sea {theSeaBeingDeleted} AND river IS NULL AND lake IS NULL;`). This way you're not updating a bunch of rows you're about to delete anyway.